# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider, Webmatrix ,Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, webmatrix

I installed WebMatrix on my Windows 8.1 computer. Now I'm trying to install wordpress from within WebMatrix. When I give it user and db info and click next.

I get this error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.
The MySQL Connector for .Net is required in order to perform this operation. Object of type 'dbMySql' and path 'server=localhost;uid=root' cannot be created. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
```